# Status of the Sarkisov program a la Corti

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

To a birational map $f$ between Mori fiber spaces, one can associate the "Sarkisov degree", a triple $(\mu,\lambda,e)$ which I will not define here.  To factor $f$ into a sequence of elementary Sarkisov links, one shows that it's always possible to find a link which improves one of these three invariants.

The termination of the Sarkisov program in dimension 3 was established by Corti, using these invariants.  However, in general the termination of the program is a difficult problem, because the set of quasi-effective thresholds $\mu$ is not discrete.

Hacon and McKernan proved the termination of the Sarkisov program by other means, circumventing the question of whether this invariant actually takes values in a discrete set.  However, in the last couple years, there has been a flurry of activity in proving various LCC, ACC, BAB,...-type conjectures, in which I am not an expert.  My question is this: does the termination of the Sarkisov program the "old way" follow from these new results?